# Is it a good practice to develop a video game for many platforms at once (using e.g. Unity)?

Tags: game-development, multi-platform

Multi-platform development tools like Unity offer us an ability to quickly deploy games to many platforms at once. However, I'm concerned about whether the final product will be any worse compared to being developed for single platform in mind.

For example, I'm creating a game with both PC and mobile device in mind. Having to support both platforms, I'll make decisions that will compromise one platform or the other, for example: I want to make a big enviorment, with many detailed objects, but I know that if I make too many objects, the game won't preform well on mobile devices (due to weaker hardware). So then I reduce the detail, but then, when played on PC, the game doesn't look as attractive, and it compromises the overall experience.

So, should one try to make the game identical on both platforms, or should one develop for a single platform at a time, and try to take advantage of the platform's capabilites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about developing for PC hardware which is more variable than phone hardware, and certainly more variable than a dedicated gaming system (e.g. PS4)?

The typical way to handle this is to have configurable options. Many PC games allow one to adjust the resolution, detail level, view distance, density of doodads (e.g. tufts of grass), and many others.

I would have a phone or tablet version that is by default configured to have graphics more manageable for that platform, and the PC version would detect the video card and self-configure to something reasonable given its power. Many games have this feature built-in: inspect the system and set the graphics to the best-looking settings that still give a good framerate.